Pandas type-specific NA value detection
pandas.DataFrame.isna returns the index of any NA-like value. However, I wish to treat differently the numeric, string or timestamp NAs.
Example that shows that pd.NA and pd.NaT are caught identically in .replace():
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

floaty = pd.Series([np.nan, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=float)
stringy = pd.Series(["one", pd.NA, "two"], dtype=str)
timy = pd.Series([datetime(2000, 1, 1), datetime(2000, 1, 2), pd.NaT], dtype="datetime64[ns]")
df = pd.DataFrame({"floaty": floaty, "stringy": stringy, "timy": timy})

print(df)

# Result:
#       floaty  stringy timy
# 0     NaN     one     2000-01-01
# 1     2.0     <NA>    2000-01-02
# 2     3.0     two     NaT

df_removed_na_string = df.replace({pd.NA: "fake_string"})
print(df_removed_na_string)

# Expected:
#       floaty  stringy     timy
# 0     NaN     one         2000-01-01
# 1     2.0     fake_string 2000-01-02
# 2     3.0     two         NaT

# Actual (in pandas 2.2.2 at least):
#       floaty  stringy     timy
# 0     NaN     one         2000-01-01
# 1     2.0     fake_string 2000-01-02
# 2     3.0     two         fake_string

Is there a way to test for a specific NA type? My workaround would be to loop through columns and act according to their dtype, but that is harder to do and would not be able to deal with object columns of mixed types.

it may be useful for you to go over the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html)

I would suggest to select the object columns, fillna, then combine_first to restore the other columns:
df.select_dtypes('object').fillna('fake_string').combine_first(df)

Alternatively use map to specifically check for pd.NA with isinstance:
df.map(lambda x: 'fake_string' if isinstance(x, pd._libs.missing.NAType) else x)

Output:
   floaty      stringy       timy
0     NaN          one 2000-01-01
1     2.0  fake_string 2000-01-02
2     3.0          two        NaT

NA instances
isinstance(pd.NA, pd._libs.missing.NAType)           # True
isinstance(pd.NaT, pd._libs.missing.NAType)          # False
isinstance(np.nan, pd._libs.missing.NAType)          # False

isinstance(pd.NA, pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType)   # False
isinstance(pd.NaT, pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType)  # True
isinstance(np.nan, pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType)  # False

